# Is there a way to execute code in python for a certain amount of time

Tags: python

For instance for 30 seconds display a 3x3 grid then after the 30 seconds print a new grid. I tried using time.sleep but it does not work. I'm still a beginner in python btw.

Something like what i tried:

```
print(grid)
time.sleep(30)
print(grid2)
```

Comment: What do you mean 'it does not work ?" Please be more specific ?

Comment: Running your code, where `grid` and `grid2` are strings, works for me. First it prints the first one, then after 30 seconds, prints the second one. Is that not what you want? Please describe what you want, in that case.

Comment: Basically, I'm using the python tkinter and in my program I've made a menu. Then if I select one of the buttons it's supposed to display the 3x3 grid that I've created for 30 seconds then clear the frame and display the 2nd grid. But the problem I get is that by using time.sleep it delays the selection of the button for 30 seconds rather then the display of the first grid.

Answer (score 0):

> for 30 seconds display...

It sounds a task executing during on time frame, take a look:

```
import datetime as d
import time

def task():
    print "printing grid 3x3..."

#30 seconds from now
END_TIME = d.datetime.now() + d.timedelta(seconds=30)

while d.datetime.now() < END_TIME:
    task()
    time.sleep(1)

# after 30s
print "after 30s..."
```

Of course, there's another way:

```
seconds, count = 30, 0

while count <= seconds:
    print count, "- ", 
    task()
    time.sleep(1);
    count += 1

print "after 30s..."
```

However, using datetime you could set script to perform during hours, days or schedule for specific date.

Comment: That will print the `printing grid 3x3...` 100s (or maybe even 1000s) of times before the loop ends - I can't be sure that is the right solution.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 yeah, you are right. Before your comment I noticed that too. I have edited the answer.